# Attempting to code (aka tearing out my hair)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tryparse

I do not have a coding background whatsoever, so I'm turning to you guys for help.  I have put about 12 hours in attempting to figure this out, using my book for school, Microsoft website, this website, a couple of friends and I can not figure out what is wrong with the code.  Yes, it is for a homework problem, I'm not asking you do to it, I'm asking someone to PLEASE explain to me WHY it doesn't work.

The idea behind the project is: 
A) select a radio button, one is for day time calling, one is night time calling, one is off-hour calling. 
B) Input the amount of minutes you talked for, select calculate
C) Magic (math) happens and pow, it gives you the number.

If Radio Day is selected, the rate is 7 cents per min., Radio Night = 12 cents per min, radio off hours = 5 cents per min.

So, with that said, here is the code for the button click event, I have tried SO many different things and it still causes the answer to be: $0.00

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim dblcharge2 As Double
    Dim dblmin As Double
    Dim blnInputOk As Boolean = True
    'give value to variables'

    If Double.TryParse(txtMin.Text, dblmin) And IsNumeric(txtMin.Text) And dblmin > 0 Then
        If radDay.Checked = True Then
            lblCharge2.Text = dblmin * 0.07
            lblCharge2.Text = dblcharge2.ToString("c")
        ElseIf radEve.Checked = True Then
            lblCharge2.Text = dblmin * 0.12
            lblCharge2.Text = dblcharge2.ToString("c")
        ElseIf radOff.Checked = True Then
            lblCharge2.Text = dblmin * 0.05
            lblCharge2.Text = dblcharge2.ToString("c")
        End If
    End If
    'Try Parse and calculate the number'
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not jquery....

Comment: Shouldn't `radDay.Checked = True` be `radDay.Checked == True`? and all others?

Comment: The == comes up with an error.  And I apologize or the jquery thing, it was a recommended tag, I didn't think it was either.

Comment: Can you place a `debugger`? and check whether code is passing through any of the `if`'s? and why you are changing `lblCharge2` text twice in each `if-else`?

Comment: I don't know what that means, but it has no issues when I start the program, it just returns the value of $0.00 no matter the combination or numbers I put in.  And the lblCharge2 is because that's how my teacher said to do it?  I have no idea, I'm clueless when it comes to coding.

Comment: What `IDE` you are using.. Hopefully **visual studio**?

Comment: Then, click to the left side of `Dim dblcharge2 As Double` and place a debugger.. it will stop there when you click `button` and you can press `F10` to verify step by step..

Comment: WOW!  Okay, so you asked why I was doing that lblCharge2 and changing it twice, and I took that out, it now calculates the number!  Okay, so, would I put that line of text after the If statement in order to convert it to $#.##?

Comment: As shown in below answer, put it in a variable and then assign it...

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set label with "dblcharge2".
Please try this:

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
  Dim dblcharge2 As Double
  Dim dblmin As Double
  Dim blnInputOk As Boolean = True
  'give value to variables'

  If Double.TryParse(txtMin.Text, dblmin) And IsNumeric(txtMin.Text) And dblmin > 0 Then
    If radDay.Checked = True Then
        dblcharge2 = dblmin * 0.07
        lblCharge2.Text = dblcharge2.ToString("c")
    ElseIf radEve.Checked = True Then
        dblcharge2 = dblmin * 0.12
        lblCharge2.Text = dblcharge2.ToString("c")
    ElseIf radOff.Checked = True Then
        dblcharge2 = dblmin * 0.05
        lblCharge2.Text = dblcharge2.ToString("c")
    End If
  End If
  'Try Parse and calculate the number'
End Sub
```

Comment: That works, thank you thank you thank you!  Okay, so, the dblecharge2 is the number given (Double) then the lbl is the output and I was basically taking the output then altering the output rather than the number?  That is how I seem to understand it.